# Google Data Studio Variance chart (positive and negative numbers different colour)

Tags: bar-chart, looker-studio

Does anyone know how to make a variance chart with green positive bars and red negative bars. Seems like a basic task to invert colours for negative values but I can't find how to do it.

Thanks

[image: Example Variance chart from Excel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that it can be achieved in a [Bar Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560) is by using the two [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770) functions below instead of a single field, in the **Metric** section (where the name of the respective field is `Metric`), and in the **Style Tab**, setting the bar colour of `Positive` to **Green** and `Negative` to **Red** then ticking **Stacked Bars**:

### 1) Positive (Colour: Green)

```
IF(Metric >= 0, Metric, NULL)
```

### 2) Negative (Red: Red)

```
IF(Metric >= 0, NULL, Metric)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/851c81fd-0d36-4342-a8d8-d75cb994e479) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TOSk4LLlHs55ICNRqHv_gzs2IuFgoTe7bit6d2wVcDI/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]